# Test exported module with Jest Mock in Vue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to make mock on exported module but I don't know how. Following is my code.

**api**

```
// @/src/api/index.js

...
export const foo = {
  fetch() {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

**vue**

```
import { foo } from '@/api' 

...
data() {
  return {
    receivedData: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  onClickButton() {
    // event listener
    foo.then(data => { this.receivedData = data }
  }
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { foo } from '@/api'
...
jest.mock('../../../src/api/index.js') // it does not mock foo

...
  beforeEach(() => {
    foo.mockClear()
    // error : _api.foo.mockClear is not a function
  })
```

In this example, how I can make mock for the `foo` that is **exported with name** not a module exported as default like `exported default foo`.

Comment: Would something like this work for you: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-214556122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**api**

```
// @/src/api/index.js

...
export const foo = {
  fetch() {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}

// add following
export default {
  foo
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import api from '@/api' // get a object which have all api functions
...
jest.mock('../../../src/api/index.js', () => {
  // make it similar with 'export default' of api/index.js
  return {
    foo: {
      fetch: jest.fn(() => {
        return {
          then(callback) {
            // pass dummy data as you want or need
            callback({ data: { success: true } })
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})

...
  beforeEach(() => {
    // clear mock of each mocked function
    api.foo.fetch.mockClear()
  })

  it('test api', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')

    expect(api.foo.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled() // pass it
  })

  it('test api2', () => {
    expect(api.foo.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled() // do not pass it
  })
```

In this way, I can handle the mock function and check the changed ui elements or vue instance's data.